# Converting UTF8 Encoded string to Jpeg image

Tags: utf8-decode

I have a string encoded in UTF-8 encoding which obviously is a jpeg image that was converted to the UTF-8 encoded text.

Now I converted a jpeg image to UTF-8 encoding and found that this string represents a JPEG image. The beginning of this string is:

> ����\0JFIF\0\0`\0`\0\0��\0C\0...

I want to convert this string back to it's JPEG format.

Can anyone be of help to me on this?

---

***edit***

What has been done is this! There is a jpeg file which was converted to utf-8 encoding using this C# code.

```
byte[] logo = null;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\logo.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))

{

       logo = new byte[fs.Length];
       fs.Read(logo, 0, logo.Length);
}

string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(logo);
```

Now str has been saved to the column in database.

I know that some bytes may have been lost in the process of encoding thus destroying our original jpg file. What I'm asking is, if there is a way to actually get back or reconstruct the .jpg file from this str.

Comment: How did you convert it? The above looks like you didn't convert it at all, but just read it as if it was UTF-8.

Comment: @Jon - looks like it. In which case he should probably just change the file extension to jpg....

Comment: I'm trying to read from a 'Long' DataType in Oracle which is used to store an image. Now this columns stores string which is similar to the above. But these strings represent images. The task now is to get the image from this string.

Comment: What are you using to get the octets out of the database again? To me this looks like it isn't UTF-8 at all, but rather it's a bunch of bytes that's being read **as if** it was UTF-8. In which case you need to instead take it out as bytes, and away you go. Just in case it really was turned into UTF-8 at some point, check that the first byte is 0xFF, since it would be in a JPEG, but is illegal in UTF-8. If something has "fixed" the UTF-8, it won't be 0xFF anymore, and you've destroyed your JPEG.

Comment: need solution how you didi it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485968/view-image-from-list-view-string-unicode-to-picture-box-parameter-not-valid   answe too similar

Comment: Hi, Edward, did you made it?